# Weak convergence equivalent to weak convergence at $0$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, weak-convergence, strong-convergence

Let $(X, \lVert \cdot \rVert)$ be a Banach space and $(T(t))_{t\geq0}$ a semigroup of linear operators , i.e for all $t, s \geq 0$ we have $T(t):X \to X$ is a linear operator, $T(t+s)=T(t)T(s)$ and $T(0)=$ Id.
For arbitrary but fixed $x\in X,~l \in X^{'}$ consider the mapping
$$
F_{l, x}: \mathbb{R}_+ \to \mathbb{R}, t \mapsto F_{l, x}(t):=l(T(t)x)
$$
Is continuity of $F_{l,x}$ at $t=0$, i.e.
$$
\underset{t\downarrow 0}{\lim} l(T(t)x) = l(x)
$$ enough for continuity everywhere?
[The motivation is 1. that weak continuity implies strong continuity, and 2. that there's the equivalent statement for strong continuity.]

Comment: $\ell$ is continuous, then $F$ is continuous $\iff$ $t\mapsto T(t)$ is continuous, $\iff$ $T$ is continuous at $t=0$.

Comment: By "$t \mapsto T(t)$ is cont." and "$T$ is continuous at $t=0$", do you mean strong continuity?
My motivation is: I have a problem where I want to prove that $(T_t)_{t\geq0}$ is strongly continuous. I can prove continuity at $0$ for $F$, so if that implies $F$ is continuous everywhere I have weak and therefore strong continuity.

Comment: No need strong continuity, only $\lim_{t\to 0}T(t)x=x.$

Comment: That is my definition of strong continuity, sorry if that was unclear. See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0-semigroup

Answer (score 2):

Yes because
$$
  l\big (T_{t+h}(x)\big ) - l\big (T_t(x)\big ) =   l\Big (T_{t}\big (T_h(x) - x\big )\Big ) =
  l'\big (T_h(x) - x\big ),
  $$
where
$
  l'=l\circ T_t.
  $

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can see why this implies right continuity, using $h>0$. However, for $h<0$ we would get $l(T_{t+h}(x)-l(T_t(x)) = (l \circ T_{t+h})(x-T_{-h}(x))$, such that $(x-T_{-h}(x))$ converges weakly by assumption, but $(l \circ T_{t+h})$ is not a fixed functional?

Comment: I think the expression in my answer works irrespective of the sign of $h$.

Comment: The problem I'm having is that $T_h$ is not defined for $h<0$, that's why I only get right continuity from your answer?

Comment: Ouch!  I now understand your point.  Let me think about it.

Comment: Any revelations? I'm at a loss

Comment: Not really, I'm sorry.  By the way what is a reference for the result regarding strong continuity?

Comment: Okay no worries. E.g. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226363792_One-Parameter_Semigroups_for_Linear_Evolution_Equations, Proposition 5.3

Comment: I just looked at the proof given there (involving the Uniform Boundedness Principle) and I think it works here too. I'll post it in a minute.